# How to Reverse inequality statement?

Tags: python, if-statement

If you multiply an inequality by a negative number you must reverse the direction of the inequality.

For example:

- 1 < x < 6 (1)
- -1 > -x > -10 (2)

if x = 6, it is consistent with equation (1) and (2).

Is there a way to multiply an inequality statement by an integer in a one-liner for Python to reverse the signs?

From the practical point of view, I am trying to extract DNA/protein sequences from TBLASTN results. There are strands +1 and -1 and the operation after that condition statement is the same.

```
# one-liner statement I would like to implement
if (start_codon <= coord <= stop_codon)*strand:
    # do operation

# two-liner statement I know would work
if (start_codon <= coord <= stop_codon) and strand==1:
    # do operation
elif (start_codon >= coord >= stop_codon) and strand==-1:
    # do operation
```

Comment: Can you give a few concrete examples of values for `start_codon`, `coord`, `stop_codon`, `strand`, and the desired outcome? I still find it hard to understand the question even after thinking about it for several minutes.

Comment: For example, it's not quite clear to me why `abs(start_codon) <= abs(coord) <= abs(stop_codon)` wouldn't work.

Comment: @mkrieger1: because it is possible that `start_codon = -1`, `coord = -0.5`, and `stop_codon = 3`, which is clearly correct (`-1 <= -0.5 <= 3`), but with `abs(..)` we get `1 <= 0.5 <= 3` which no longer works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could select the lower and upper bounds based on the `strand` value. This assumes that `strand` is always either `1` or `-1` and makes use of `bool` being an `int` subclass in Python so that `True` and `False` can be used to index into pairs:

```
cdns = (start_codon, stop_codon)
if (cdns[strand==-1] <= coord <= cdns[strand==1]):
    # Python type coercion (True -> 1, False -> 0) in contexts requiring integers
```

Comment: Nice solution, however it is worthy to notice this is language dependent: not all the languages index tuples with bools where true=1 false=0 like Python does.

Comment: @Fabio Veronese Thats why this question is tagged with python, and not other languages.

Comment: @RoadRunner it is indeed - mine was a brief annotation for any random reader with same problem and different coding language.

Comment: @Fabio Veronese Good point,  would be more helpful for a broader range of readers.

Comment: @FabioVeronese I added some explanation. Makes sense to mention it, even for Python users who might be unaware this option.

Answer (score 4):

## Using negation to reverse operations

You write it like:

```
if (start_codon <= coord <= stop_codon) and strand==1:
    # do operation
elif (start_codon >= coord >= stop_codon) and strand==-1:
    # do operation
```

But this is equivalent to:

```
if abs(strand) == 1 and strand * start_codon <= strand * coord <= strand * stop_codon:
    # do operation
    pass
```

Or in case we can make the assumption that `abs(strand) == 1` always holds:

```
if strand * start_codon <= strand * coord <= strand * stop_codon:
    # do operation
    pass
```

## Theoretical proof

This works since **`x >= y`, is equilvalent to `-x <= -y`**. So instead of "reversing" the condition, we multiply both operands with `-1`, and thus *implicitly* reverse the condition. Let us take the example:

In case `strand == 1`, then we thus evaluate `-start_codon <= -coord <= -stop_codon`. This is equivalent to `-start_codon <= -coord and -coord <= -stop_codon`. Now we can normalize the two subexpressions with `start_codon >= coord and coord >= stop_codon` which is equivalent to `start_codon >= coord coord >= stop_codon`. So this means that **`-start_codon <= -coord <= -stop_codon` is equivalent to `start_codon >= coord >= stop_codon`**.

We make a single assumption: that is that `start_codon` and `stop_codon` are *numbers* (such that we can multiply these).

## Empirical evidence

We can generate empirical evidence for this relation emprically as well by the following setup:

```
import numpy as np

test_size = 1000
a = np.random.randn(test_size, 4)  # generate 1000x4 matrix of random data
a[:,3] = np.sign(a[:,3])  # make the last column -1 and 1
assert not (a[:,3] == 0).any()  # check no zeros in the last column
b = np.zeros(test_size)  # results for our relation
c = np.zeros(test_size)  # results for the question implementation

for i, (start_codon, coord, stop_codon, strand) in enumerate(a):
    b[i] = strand * start_codon <= strand * coord <= strand * stop_codon
    if (start_codon <= coord <= stop_codon) and strand==1:
        c[i] = 1
    elif (start_codon >= coord >= stop_codon) and strand==-1:
        c[i] = 1
    else:
        c[i] = 0

assert (b == c).all()
```

## Performance

If we take the above code, we can slighly modify it to check performance as follows:

```
import numpy as np
from operator import ge, le

test_size = 100000
a = np.random.randn(test_size, 4)  # generate 1000x4 matrix of random data
a[:,3] = np.sign(a[:,3])  # make the last column -1 and 1
assert not (a[:,3] == 0).any()  # check no zeros in the last column
b = np.zeros(test_size)  # target array

def code_kevin():
    for i, (start_codon, coord, stop_codon, strand) in enumerate(a):
        if (start_codon <= coord <= stop_codon) and strand==1:
            b[i] = 1
        elif (start_codon >= coord >= stop_codon) and strand==-1:
            b[i] = 1

def code_schwo():
    for i, (start_codon, coord, stop_codon, strand) in enumerate(a):
        cdns = (start_codon, stop_codon)
        if (cdns[strand==-1] <= coord <= cdns[strand==1]):
            b[i] = 1

def code_moinu():
    for i, (start_codon, coord, stop_codon, strand) in enumerate(a):
        codon_check = (le, ge)[strand==1]
        if codon_check(start_codon, coord) and codon_check(coord, stop_codon):
            b[i] = 1

def code_wille():
    for i, (start_codon, coord, stop_codon, strand) in enumerate(a):
        if strand * start_codon <= strand * coord <= strand * stop_codon:
            b[i] = 1

def code_fabio():
    for i, (start_codon, coord, stop_codon, strand) in enumerate(a):
        if pow(start_codon/coord, strand) <= 1 <= pow(stop_codon/coord, strand):
            b[i] = 1
```

so as operations, we use `b[i] = 1`. We furthermore always use `if` statements (and not assign a boolean directly) to make the comparison timings more fair.

We can then use `timeit.timeit`, to run every function a number of times, and time the number of seconds it takes:

```
>>> timeit.timeit(code_kevin, number=100)
8.667507636011578
>>> timeit.timeit(code_schwo, number=100)
10.56048975896556
>>> timeit.timeit(code_wille, number=100)
8.908266504004132
>>> timeit.timeit(code_fabio, number=100)
13.454442486981861
>>> timeit.timeit(code_moinu, number=100)
10.350756354047917
```

Comment: Based on the given  working two-liner, `coord` itself doesn't change with the `strand`

Comment: But this *doesn't* reverse the inequality operator, which is supposed to be the whole point.

Comment: @schwobaseggl: now, but in order to reverse the questions, both operands have to be multiplied with `-1`.

Comment: Let me think about that for a bit longer... ;)

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem True, this answers the general question of multiplying a equation with a negative number, but for the specific case, the OP doesn't even claim that `start_codon == -stop_codon` which would be required.

Comment: @schwobaseggl: it is not, by multiplying with `-1`, we simply reverse the comparisons implicitly. `startcodon == stopcodon` is *not* a requirement. You forget that we also negate `coord`.

Comment: @schowbaseggl: see last paragraph of the edited answer.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I understand, but for `strand == -1` the OP basically wants `start_cdn` and `stop_cdn` swapped while you simply negate them (thus implicitly assuming `start_codon == -stop_codon`)

Comment: @schwobaseggl: no, since **the sandwiched value is also negated**. If I would have written `-start_codon <= coord <= -stop_codon`, you would be right, but `coord` is **also negated**. What is not correct about the proof at the last section? Can you give a single counter example (so probably with `start_codon != -stop_codon`) where this case fails?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Which brings me back to my initial comment. This answerrs the general point of how to multiply an equation with -1, not the specific question of how to simplify the given two if-statements into a single one which given the code is *not* an instantiation of the former problem.

Comment: @schwobaseggl: but we do *not* change `coord` at all. We only calculate the negation to let mathematics do the magic. `coord` remains unchanged. As said before, give me a single counter-example.

Comment: @schwobaseggl: compare it to calculating that a coordinate is within a circle with radius `d`, we can do this with `sqrt(x*x+y*y) <= d`. We can calculate that with `sqrt`, but `sqrt` is a slow operation, so frequently it is done with `x*x+y*y <= d*d`, so it is equivalent. We did not change the semantics of the distance function (it is still with the square root), but we found a way to move sqrt out of the equation.

Comment: @schwobaseggl: I also wrote a test setup to generate emperical evidence that the conditions are equivalent. With a `test_size` of 1'000, it succeeds.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162689/discussion-between-schwobaseggl-and-willem-van-onsem).

Answer (score 1):

You can use simply math:

```
# one-liner statement
if pow(start_codon/coord, strand) <= 1 <= pow(stop_codon/coord, strand):
    # do operation

# two-liner statement I know would work
if (start_codon <= coord <= stop_codon) and strand==1:
    # do operation
elif (start_codon >= coord >= stop_codon) and strand==-1:
    # do operation
```

since x^-1 makes the inversion of the ratios *de facto* inverting the comparison directions

Comment: I think this can be quite unsafe, since `coord` can be zero (or close to zero). Furthermore it would convert an *integer* number to *floating* points, and floating punts are quite unsafe for comparisons (since these are subject to rounding errors).

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem you are right, in case coord is 0 this trows an exception - division by zero - however it can be easily checked. Concerning safeness it is something to consider too, I checked and this solution holds approx up to 10^15.

Answer (score 1):

Functional approach using [**`ge`**](http://%20%20%20[2]:%20https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.ge) and [**`le`**](http://%20%20%20[2]:%20https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.ge) from the [`operator`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html) library:

```
from operator import ge, le

# Sets `codon_check` function as:
#     - `ge`   if "strand == 1"
#     - `le`   otherwise 
codon_check = (le, ge)[strand==1]

if codon_check(start_codon, coord) and codon_check(coord, stop_codon):
    # do operation
```

---

Here:

- [**`ge(a, b)`**](http://%20%20%20[2]:%20https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.ge) checks whether `a >= b`.
- [**`le(a, b)`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html) checks whether `a <= b`.